# Using for loops to sort strings

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to use two for loops to sort a list of strings alphabetically.

Specifically I am not allowed to use `java.util.Collections.sort()`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < str.size(); j++)
    {
        if(str.get(i).compareTo(str.get(j))< 0)
        {
            String temp;
            str.add(temp);
            str.set(str.get(temp),str.get(i));
            str.set(i, str.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far. The idea is that it could work with any list. The main problem I keep getting is how to add a temporary string in order to retain the data in `i` and `j`.

Comment: First thing to learn is that Java and JavaScript are not the same :) It is common to say that they are as related as car is related to carpet.

Comment: The goal is to swap the values at `i` and `j`. So `get` and `set` are good. However, `add` does not belong here. You're not adding anything to the list, you're changing the values at `i` and `j`. In any case, please ask your teacher for a clarification. He/she is in better position to help you than SO could possibly be.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to add the temporary string to the arraylist you are sorting - you should use it to swap the two values instead:

```
String temp = str.get(i);
str.set(i, str.get(j)); // this overwrites str.get(i),
                        // hence the need for temp
str.set(j, temp);
```

Also, what you are doing is not really bubble sort :-)

Wikipedia has nice articles on the most common algorithms/problems and is a great resource for starting with programming, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Welcome to the programming bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. It is good to see that you have tried something on your own before coming here. There are other sorting techniques that are faster than Bubble Sort. Please try them if possible.

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
    str.add("bbbb");
    str.add("aaaa");
    str.add("cccc");

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < str.size(); j++)
        {
            if(str.get(i).compareTo(str.get(j))< 0)
            {

                String temp = str.get(i);
                str.set(i, str.get(j));
                str.set(j, temp);

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(str);  //this will print cccc,bbbb,aaaa
```